# Using regression output outside chunk and inside text in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am doing repeated analysis for various regression techniques in a report I am doing. I can do the regression fine, however I would like to get the regression output and put it into text. I make a reproducible example below:

```
linearMod <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)  # build linear regression model on full data
print(linearMod)
```

With the output being:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        speed  
    -17.579        3.932
```

How would I get this into some R markdown text. For example, I would want to write: The linear regression model found that dist=-17.579+3.932Speed, with speed being statistically significant

I realise I can do this manually by typing, but this becomes more difficult and cumbersome when there are many variables involved, which in my case there can be around 10, with multiple regression equations in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display any R variable/expression in Markdown using `r VariableName
On your example :

```
The linear regression model found that dist=`r linearMod$coefficients[1]` + `r linearMod$coefficients[2]` Speed.
```

[image]